# Can we use the modal verb "could" in the present and future to show possibilities?

Tags: modal-verbs, american-english, british-english

I have some basic knowledge of English grammar (this is what I think!!!).  I have a question about the modal verbs *can* and *could*. Let me share what I know about these modal verbs. I have explained both the modal verbs below to make you understand what knowledge I have about them:

> Can:
>
> It can be used to show abilities, opportunities, possibilities and
>   take permissions and requests  (only in the present time).
>
> Could:
>
> It can be used in the past and present times. It can be used
>   to show abilities, opportunities, possibilities (in the past as it is
>   the past form of can), but it can also be used to take permissions and
>   requests (in the present).

**My question is can we use *could* in the present and future  to show possibilities?**

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks, sorry it was a typo mistake. I have fixed it. Thanks again:)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we can use "could" to talk about possibility in the present or future. For example, don't eat this bread; it could be stale. He was sent to prison two months ago, and could be released next week.

Answer (score 1):

Why not? *Could* is not restricted to those tenses. For instance,

> [*Could I speak to 'x'?*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Could+I+speak+to%3F) 
>   [*If we don’t hurry we could be late*](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/modal-verbs/can-or-could)

We generally use this phrase to speak to someone else. *Could* over *Can* simply reflects that you are more polite. Check that you have not spoken to someone else, so it's a kind of future. The word *could* is used in present *but in conditional* context.